# Linux headers generic package not found

Tags: raspbian, kernel

I need to compile this [driver](https://github.com/dz0ny/rt8192cu), however I'm missing my kernel headers. I've tried installing them the normal way:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

> Package 'linux-headers-generic' has no instalation candidate

And:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

> E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.1.18-v7

Neither worked, I've search the apt database for "linux-headers":

```
apt-cache search linux-headers

linux-headers-3.10-3-all - All header files for Linux 3.10 (meta-package)
linux-headers-3.10-3-all-armhf - All header files for Linux 3.10 (meta-package)
linux-headers-3.10-3-common - Common header files for Linux 3.10-3
linux-headers-3.10-3-rpi - Header files for Linux 3.10-3-rpi
linux-headers-3.12-1-all - All header files for Linux 3.12 (meta-package)
linux-headers-3.12-1-all-armhf - All header files for Linux 3.12 (meta-package)
linux-headers-3.12-1-common - Common header files for Linux 3.12-1
linux-headers-3.12-1-rpi - Header files for Linux 3.12-1-rpi
linux-headers-3.16.0-4-all - All header files for Linux 3.16 (meta-package)
linux-headers-3.16.0-4-all-armhf - All header files for Linux 3.16 (meta-package)
linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common - Common header files for Linux 3.16.0-4
linux-headers-3.16.0-4-rpi - Header files for Linux 3.16.0-4-rpi
linux-headers-3.18.0-trunk-all - All header files for Linux 3.18 (meta-package)
linux-headers-3.18.0-trunk-all-armhf - All header files for Linux 3.18 (meta-package)
linux-headers-3.18.0-trunk-common - Common header files for Linux 3.18.0-trunk
linux-headers-3.18.0-trunk-rpi - Header files for Linux 3.18.0-trunk-rpi
linux-headers-3.18.0-trunk-rpi2 - Header files for Linux 3.18.0-trunk-rpi2
linux-headers-3.6-trunk-all - All header files for Linux 3.6 (meta-package)
linux-headers-3.6-trunk-all-armhf - All header files for Linux 3.6 (meta-package)
linux-headers-3.6-trunk-common - Common header files for Linux 3.6-trunk
linux-headers-3.6-trunk-rpi - Header files for Linux 3.6-trunk-rpi
linux-headers-rpi - Header files for Linux rpi configuration (meta-package)
linux-headers-rpi-rpfv - This metapackage will pull in the headers for the raspbian kernel for the
linux-headers-rpi2-rpfv - This metapackage will pull in the headers for the raspbian kernel for the
```

How can I install the kernel headers for **4.1.18-v7+**?

I'm using the latest version of Raspbian (headless) fully updated:

Linux localhost 4.1.18-v7+ #848 SMP Mon Feb 29 14:19:45 GMT 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux

Thank you.

Comment: You did `sudo apt-get update` first, right?

Comment: Of course I did.

Comment: It is not possible to add kernel module derived from 4.14 header files to 4.1.18-v7+ kernel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where do I find the linux headers for an image?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37589/where-do-i-find-the-linux-headers-for-an-image)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also came across this problem and solved it by following the instructions [for a similar question on this forum](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1273/where-is-the-kernel-source-for-raspbians-default-3-1-9-kernel).

However I did need to make some changes. Specifically, I had to run the following commands:

```
cd /usr/src
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux.git
ln -s linux linux-4.1.18-v7+
ln -s /usr/src/linux /lib/modules/4.1.18-v7+/build
cd linux
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/raspberrypi/firmware/master/extra/Module.symvers
make menuconfig
make prepare
make modules_prepare
```

After that, I could compile my kernel module.

Notes I

- I did this on `Raspbian GNU/Linux 8`, `Linux raspberrypi 4.1.18-v7+ #846 SMP Thu Feb 25 14:22:53 GMT 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux` on Raspberry Pi 3
- If you need to make use of a specific version of the kernel, [this would be of interest](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37010/rpi2-kernel-module-compilation-kernel-3-18-11-vs-3-18-11-v7/37011#37011)

Comment: Interesting. I already have a folder `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.1.18-v7+` shouldn't these be the headers?

Comment: yes that should do it. On mine I did not have the header files. Someone else seems to have prepared a deb file (for those in the same situation as myself) that also worked for me: https://www.niksula.hut.fi/~mhiienka/Rpi/linux-headers-rpi/

Comment: Yes, I've tried it, specifically this one `linux-headers-4.1.18-v7+_4.1.18-v7+-2_armhf.deb` however during `dpkg --install` it gets stuck extracting and that's the end of it. I will try it one more time, maybe clean up this Raspbian instance before.

Answer (score 4):

Run below command on the terminal to install

```
 sudo apt install raspberrypi-kernel-headers
```

Comment: Yes. Don't forget to run 'sudo apt-get update' before it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a script maintained on Github which will download the matching kernel sources https://github.com/notro/rpi-source/wiki for the kernel in use.

The documentation says:

> rpi-source installs the kernel source used to build rpi-update kernels and the kernel on the Raspian image.
>   This makes it possible to build loadable kernel modules.
>   It is not possible to build modules that depend on missing parts that need to be built into the kernel proper (bool in Kconfig).
>
> The script uses sudo internally when self-updating and when making the links /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/{build,source}
>
> Note: rpi-source is supported from Linux version 3.10.37 (when Module.symvers appeared in the repo)

Answer (score 2):

`linux-headers-rpi` appears to be the meta-package which installs the latest kernel headers. This is what you should use on a fully upgraded system. You will need to manually rebuild your custom drivers after a kernel upgrade, but at least the kernel headers will be upgraded automatically.