# Linux headers in Raspbian Jessie

Tags: raspbian, apt, software-compilation

I have problem to install `linux-headers` in Raspbian on my RPi2. My kernel version is 4.1.17-v7+. I can't find the `linux-headers` package with `apt-get`.

Comment: You can find the answer here in this similar question: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43619/linux-headers-generic-package-not-found/43903#43903

Answer (score 6):

You can try `sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-kernel-headers` if you're running raspbian.

As suggested here 
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=154749

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-cache search linux-headers
```

It will list you the related packages.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment there is no `linux-headers` for the 4.1.17 kernel version.

There are only headers for the 4.1.19 version for the 4.x branch. You can simply upgrade your kernel to the 4.1.19 version (now the newest stable branch showing 4.1.20):

```
sudo rpi-update f406502f5628d32e6ca5dadac34ff7ca59f8e27f
```

After install reboot your device and check typing `uname -r` if there is a 4.1.19-v7+ version. If it's OK, install linux-headers:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-4.1.19-v7+
```

Comment: I updated my kernel to 4.1.20-v7+ by rpi-update but Raspbian's repo doesn't have any headers for 4.x kernel ;( Any solution how to install it?

Comment: You tried my rpi-update with this git hash ? It should update to 4.1.19 version. If this not you can try use other hash like:
**7e4f4cb0bf8c8f7469727d5b710818c3e6eea289** . It points to 4.1.19 kernel version

Comment: It won't help to solve that problem because raspian doesn't have headers newer than 3.18 in repo. I solved it by other way. I used "rpi-source" script which downloading and installing source for kernel. Thanks for your attepmts to help me ;)